# reactjs componentWillUnmount is not being called

Tags: reactjs

I have build a form, where there is dropdown on which selection below fields will be displayed. So say, first `optionSet1` was selected for which there was 3 field to be shown. If user changes dropdown to select `optionSet2`, different set of options will be shown.

But when `optionSet2` is being rendered and `optionSet1` is removed it should have called `componentWillUnmount` for the each `InputFields` rendered previously, which is not the case. This function is never called.

```
class LeadUpdate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  _getUpdateFields() {
    let fields = this.props.inputFields[this.state.updateType];

    return _.map(fields, f => {
      _.assignIn(f, {
        fieldParentClass: 'form-group col-lg-6',
        eventName: this.state.eventName
      });
      return <InputField config={f} />
    });
  }

  _onChange(id, value) {
    this.setState({
      optionSet: value
    });
  }

  render() {
   return  (<div>
      <div className="col-lg-5">
        <form role="form" className="vymo-form">
          <InputField values={this.props.values} onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} />
        </form>
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <form role="form" className="vymo-form">
          {this._getUpdateFields()}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>)
  }
}
```

Update: I have just realised that componentWillUnmount is being called but the actual problem is with eventListner. I am pasting codes here.

Problem -- I am using nodejs events for getting values from different input fields populated. But when optionSet changes all previous unmounted options are also listening to event.

InputField --

```
import eventsService from '../../../services/events-service';

class InputField extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.id,
            value: this._getInputFieldValue() || '',
            valid: true,
            errorVisible: false,
            errorMessage: ''
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        if(this.props.eventName) {
            this._subscription = eventsService.emitter.addListener(this.props.eventName, this._validate.bind(this));
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if(this.props.eventName) {
            eventsService.emitter.removeListener(this.props.eventName, this._validate.bind(this));
        }
    }

    _handleChange(event) {

        if(this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange.call(null, this.state.id, event.target.value);
        }
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        });
    }

    _getClasses(classes) {
        if (classes) {
            return classes.join(' ');
        }
    }

    _getInputFieldProps() {
        let inputProps = {
            value: this.state.value,
            type: this.props.type,
            placeholder: this.props.placeholder || '',
            id: this.props.id,
            onChange: this._handleChange.bind(this),
            className: this._getClasses(this.props.classes) ? this._getClasses(this.props.classes) + 'form-control' : 'form-control',
            maxlength: this.props.maxLength,
            disabled: this.props.disabled ? "true" : null,
            min: this.props.min,
            max: this.props.max,
            readOnly: this.props.readonly ? "true" : null,
            required: this.props.required
        };

        return inputProps;
    }

    _validate(result) {
        if (this.props.required && !this.state.value) {
            valid = false;
            this.setState({
                errorVisible: true,
                errorMessage: 'this is required field',
                valid: false
            });
        }


        if(valid) {
            this.setState({
                errorVisible: false,
                errorMessage: 'this is not a valid phone number',
                valid: true
            });
        }

        result.valid &= valid;
        result.values.push({
            type: this.props.type,
            code: this.state.id,
            value: this.state.value,
            name: this.props.label
        });


    }

    _getInputFieldValue() {
        switch (this.props.type) {
            case Types.NUMBER:
            case Types.EMAIL:
            case Types.DECIMAL:
            case Types.PHONE:
            case Types.TEXT:
                return this.props.value;
        }
    }

    render() {
        let props = this._getInputFieldProps();
        return (<div className={this.props.fieldParentClass}>
            <label for={this.props.id}><span>{this.props.label}</span><span>{props.required ? '*' : ''}</span></label>
            <input {...props}/>
            <span className={this.state.errorVisible ? 'show' : 'hide'}>{this.state.errorMessage}</span>
        </div>)
    }

}
```

event service:--

```
import {EventEmitter} from  'events';
//TODO make this as constant
var emmiter = new EventEmitter();
export default {
    emitter: emmiter,

}
```

I understand this event service is bad, its just was for quickly test this functionality.

Comment: Can you please share more info? I don't see `componentWillUnmount` here and also render() doesn't return proper syntax. Thank you.

Comment: yeah, removed unnecessary codes. just to make it simple. Wrapped it in div so now it will return valid html. @Grgur

Comment: I fixed your code formatting, but first I also added a `return` to your `render` method, but I removed it again, in case the missing `return` was relevant to your problems.

Comment: In case you didn't know, you'll need to bind _onClick to `this`. It's best to do this in the `constructor`, i.e. `this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);` If you omitted this from your snippet here, because you thought it wasn't relevant, think again. It's better to include too much code here, than too little.

Comment: Sorry guys, just to give the snapshot of code removed many things just to focus on issue. Lets focus on the real problem here. I will edit your kind suggestions though. Thanks

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Looks like a bug in React. I've read that this *should* work http://buildwithreact.com/article/component-lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

The `Field` component remains mounted, in this case you need to use [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) to identify which component has changed, added, or removed:

```
{this.state.mode === 'custom' ?
    <Field
        label="A"
        name="requested_completes"
        type="number"
        key="a"
    />
    :
    <Field
        label="B"
        name="requested_completes"
        type="dropdown"
        key="b"
    />
}
```