# componentWillUnmount method not called when react Component disapears

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I have a problem understanding why in some cases `componentWillUnmount` method is not called even if the component I would expect is unmounted.

To be more concrete, this is the example. Let's consider a Parent component with a button and 2 children: Child_Odd and Child_Even. Child_Odd is "shown" if the number of clicks of the button is odd, otherwise Child_Even is "shown".

I would expect to see the the `componentWillUnmount` method to be called when the component "disappears", but on the contrary this does not happen. [Here a stackblitz reproducing the case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hou4hl?file=index.tsx) (this stackblitz includes also a similar case where the `componentWillUnmount` method is actually called).

This is the relevant code

```
export class ChildFlipped extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.name} - No of clicks ({this.props.numberOfClicks})
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class ParentFlips extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clickCounter: 0,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.updateState()}
        >
          Click me
        </button>
        {this.state.clickCounter % 2 ? (
          <ChildFlipped
            name={"Even"}
            numberOfClicks={this.state.clickCounter}
          ></ChildFlipped>
        ) : (
          <ChildFlipped
            name={"Odd"}
            numberOfClicks={this.state.clickCounter}
          ></ChildFlipped>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
  updateState() {
    this.setState((prevState, _props) => ({
      clickCounter: prevState.clickCounter + 1,
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reactjs componentWillUnmount is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052402/reactjs-componentwillunmount-is-not-being-called)

Comment: That answer doesn't really explain anything though, it just shows how to remedy it with keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't fire because the component remains mounted. With respect to reconciliation, the conditional expression

```
this.state.clickCounter % 2
? <ChildFlipped name={"Even"} numberOfClicks={this.state.clickCounter}/>
: <ChildFlipped name={"Odd"} numberOfClicks={this.state.clickCounter}/>
```

is indistinguishable from

```
<ChildFlipped name={this.state.clickCounter % 2? "Even" : "Odd"} 
              numberOfClicks={this.state.clickCounter}/>
```

since both clauses refer to the same `ChildFlipped` component. If you add keys, you can make them distinguishable and trigger unmounting:

```
his.state.clickCounter % 2
? <ChildFlipped key='even' name={"Even"} numberOfClicks={this.state.clickCounter}/>
: <ChildFlipped key='odd' name={"Odd"} numberOfClicks={this.state.clickCounter}/>
```

For experimenting with lifecycle methods I built a [React lifecycle visualizer](https://github.com/Oblosys/react-lifecycle-visualizer#readme) ([StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/Oblosys/react-lifecycle-visualizer/tree/master/examples/parent-child-demo?file=src/samples/New.js)) which may be useful for you.